# Repeat function until true in Python

Tags: python

googled a lot but I still have no solution
So I have a parser def:

```
def parse_page(url):

    req = request.get(url, headers=headers(), proxies=dict(http='socks4://' + get_proxy()), timeout=5)
```

(code was just for example)

Sometimes proxy is dead or other error could happened (timeout, err 500) but I need to make this request anyway and try until it will return true

So how can I do that?

I tried *retrying* lib but no success

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a `while` loop?

Comment: Im an idiot, coding for 20hrs+. Im really sorry for your time.

Comment: Happens to the best of us

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import time
req = 0
while not req:
    try:
        req = request.get(url, headers=headers(), proxies=dict(http='socks4://' + get_proxy()))

    except:
        time.sleep(5)
```

As soon as you get a `req` this will be `True` no matter what it is, so long as it's not `None` and that will exit the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
while parse_page(url,urls[url]) == False:
    print('Something happened... Trying again...')
else:
    print(url + 'Is saved.. Keep going...')
```

Just have to swtich while to False and thats it...

I will leave it if somebody will google it.

Comment: Be careful, I think your method does not return anthing.
And as a side note, you should avoid using == to evaluate booleans since there are already boolean :)